# How can i remove a button that i added to the ribbon in Microsoft CRM?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, ribbon

I was adding a button to the ribbon of the lead form in Microsoft Dynamics CRM, by uploading a web resource with all its resources and JavaScript code. I need to remove it now, so I deleted the solution that was imported but the button is still showing. Any idea why? What should be done in order to delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go in and remove the button XML from the customizations.

On a related note, unless your solution is managed, deleting the solution doesn't actually do anything.  Think of a solution as a way to group the things you are working on like a VS solution.  Although all your .cs (or .vb) files are part of your VS solution, if a change is made to one of the .cs files outside VS, that change still effects the .cs file in VS.  Likewise, if you delete your VS solution file, the .cs files still exist as they are.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this fantastic visual tool to edit ribbons.

http://crmvisualribbonedit.codeplex.com/